# after upgrade from 8 to 9 ng build error: Importing unexpected symbol invalidFactory while compiling angular/core

Tags: angular

after running angular upgrade I get the following error:

> Compiling @angular/core : module as esm5 Error: Error on worker #2:
>   Error: Importing unexpected symbol ɵɵinvalidFactory while compiling
>   @angular/core
>       at Object.validateAndRewriteCoreSymbol (C:\sites\regent-dev\Website\DesktopModules\RegentApp\node_modules@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\imports\src\core.js:90:19)

I ran  **ng update @angular/cli@9 @angular/core@9 --force** to upgrade from 8 to 9 because there were peer dependency issues.

As soon as this was done I ran ng build and the above error appeared. 
So i tried to following to fix it:

- rollback all the changes
- remove `node_modules` folder  `rm -rf node_modules`
- remove the `package-lock.json` file
- `npm i`
- `npm install @angular/cli -g`
- `ng update @angular/cli @angular/core --force`
- `ng update --all --force`

The error still appears

Can someone help me figure out what is going on here?

Thanks in advance

Here is the error that gets thrown when running the postinstall ngcc

```
$ npm i

> my-app@1.3.51 postinstall C:\sites\...\App
> ngcc

Warning: Entry point '@angular/core' contains deep imports into 'C:/sites/.../node_modules/ng2-bootstrap-growl/node_modules/rxjs/symbol/observable', 'C:/sites/.../node_modules/ng2-bootstrap-growl/node_modules/rxjs/Subject', 'C:/sites/.../node_modules/ng2-bootstrap-growl/node_modules/rxjs/Observable'. This is probably not a problem, but may cause the compilation of entry points to be out of order.
Compiling @angular/core : fesm2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/core : main as umd
Error: Error on worker #2: Error: Importing unexpected symbol ɵɵinvalidFactory while compiling @angular/core
    at Object.validateAndRewriteCoreSymbol (C:
... Stack Trace Continues ...
```

the following is my angular version(after upgrade and the one throwing the error):

```
Angular CLI: 9.1.7
Node: 10.15.0
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 9.1.9
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, platform-server
... router
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.901.7
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.901.7
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.901.7
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.901.7
@angular-devkit/core              9.1.7
@angular-devkit/schematics        9.1.7
@angular/cdk                      9.2.4
@angular/cli                      9.1.7
@ngtools/webpack                  9.1.7
@schematics/angular               9.1.7
@schematics/update                0.901.7
rxjs                              6.5.5
typescript                        3.9.3
webpack                           4.42.0
```

Comment: you can create empty Angular 9 project and compare 'ng --version' for both. peer dependency issues still there and you should check is there lastest version available for them

Comment: @Radik I created a new v9 project and the version files don't show the same files but the ones shown do match version. So I directly compared the package.json files.  I found a version mismatch primarily in the jasmine, karma, protractor and ts-node,tslint packages. I updated the version to match the new project and error still appears

Comment: next thing you can try copy angular.json and tsconfig* from new project

Comment: can you give your complete error trace?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using a outdated package i.e. ng2-bootstrap which is not compatible with ivy.

Set enableIvy to false in your tsconfig.app.json like :-

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
    "types": []
  },
  "files": [
    "src/main.ts",
    "src/polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ],
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableIvy": false
  }
}
```

if you want to use ivy. update your ng2-bootstrap to ngx-bootstrap and make necessary code changes as per ngx-bootstrap > 5.1.0.

Note :- if you have other external dependencies which are not ivy compatible, either you need to find a ivy compatible version, or have to keep enableIvy false.

Comment: thanks akash, you are right, that package and a couple more were not compatible with ivy, I updated the needed ones and I found a couple unused ones that I removed.  It works now.